# Why do I have two boxes viewed?

Tags: html, css

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/B7usj/

There should be just one box containing informations when I move mouse over "12 szt.", "6 szt." or "zobacz szczegóły", but there are two boxes. I have no idea, why.

CSS:

```
#sztuki {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   min-height: 16px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 5%;
   margin-right: 5%;
   bottom: 116px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have an extra div inside the div that contains `a href="index.html">Zobacz szczegóły</a> >`

First of all you should probably try using ids and classes for these things.

Without spending much time on your code because it's a mess, try to fix starting from using this:

```
<div><a href="index.html">Zobacz szczegóły</a> >

                <div>
                    6 szt.
                  <span>
                     Donec consectet
                     <span>
                        Guad sed sem auris non turpis
                     </span>
                  </span>
                      </div>

            </div>
```

It will only have one box appear, but the spans will display text visually faulty.

Comment: yes, same with all three